# How to call substring() with variables?

Tags: postgresql, substring, plpgsql

How to call the `substring()` function with variables for the `start` & `count` parameters? Below example code is not working.

```sql
DO
$$
 declare
    v_idx numeric(3);
    v_ch char(1);
    v_string varchar(50);
 begin
     v_idx := 1;
     v_string := 'My String';
      WHILE v_idx < LENGTH(v_string)
     LOOP
        v_ch := substring(v_string, v_idx, 1);  -- here!
        raise notice 'Value: %', v_ch;
        v_idx := v_idx + 1;
     END LOOP;
end;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```sql
DO
$$
DECLARE
   _string text := 'My String';
   _start  int := 1;            -- integer!
   _count  int := 1;            -- integer!
   _substr text;
BEGIN
   FOR _start IN 1 .. length(_string)
   LOOP
      _substr := substring(_string, _start, _count);
      RAISE NOTICE 'Substring from % for %: %', _start, _count, _substr;
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Produces:

```
NOTICE:  Substring from 1 for 1: M
NOTICE:  Substring from 2 for 1: y
NOTICE:  Substring from 3 for 1:  
NOTICE:  Substring from 4 for 1: S
NOTICE:  Substring from 5 for 1: t
NOTICE:  Substring from 6 for 1: r
NOTICE:  Substring from 7 for 1: i
NOTICE:  Substring from 8 for 1: n
NOTICE:  Substring from 9 for 1: g
```

Mostly because [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) expects **`integer`** input for `start` and `count` (not `numeric`).
There was also an off-by-1 error in your loop, which I replaced with a simpler, cheaper, correct `FOR` loop.

You can init variables at declaration time.

BTW, the documented standard SQL syntax for `substring()` is:

```
substring(_string FROM _start FOR _count)
```

But the Postgres implementation with just commas works, too.